# Crystal Report XI simple If then else statement NOT working

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a simple code if the the "Field_name) is less than "Date"
diesplay 'Y' else 'N', I am not not sure why crystal is ignoring the Condition and only seems to be displaying the else part.  I am getting all 'N's even when there supposed to be 'Y's.  Does anyone else come across with this issue, Please HELP!!!

code:

```
(case when ((select Distinct y.szrclin_pidm 
             from szrclin y
             where szrclin_start_date < '01-JAN-2011'
             and y.szrclin_pidm = spriden_pidm ) is not null)
           then 'Y'
           else 'N' 
       end ) "Prior Rotations"
```

Comment: i suggest you re-write the question. as it stands this appears to be a sql question not a crystal reports question. use some formatting around your code too

Answer (score 0):

The code you have doesn't make much sense in the context of Crystal Reports. My suggestion would be to use a simple formula instead.

`if {szrclin.szrclin_start_date} < date(2011,01,01) and {szrclin.szrclin_pidm} = szrclin.spriden.pidm} then 'Y' else 'N'`

If the szrclin table is in your report, I don't see any reason to use SQL Expressions for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You may indeed embed 'raw' SQL in Crystal Reports: either as SQL Expression field (returns a scalar value) OR using a Command (returns a recordset).  Use of one precludes the use of the other.  In this situation, I would suggest a SQL Expression. I've made a guess at what you are trying to do, but you'll need to validate it.

```
(
SELECT count(spriden_pidm)
FROM   szrclin y
WHERE  szrclin_start_date < '01-JAN-2011'
//correlate to 'main' query
AND    y.szrclin_pidm = spriden_pidm
GROUP BY spriden_pidm
)
```